# How to define resource limits and calculate consumption when deploying applications in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to deploy a simple zookeeper ensemble following the tutorial from the [official Kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/). The tutorial states that I need

> a cluster with at least four nodes and each node requires at least 2
> CPUs and 4 GiB of memory.

I ignored this fact and created a cluster with 3 nodes of n1-standard-1 (1 vCPU, 3.73 GB Memory)
When I tried to apply .yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-hs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 2888
      name: server
    - port: 3888
      name: leader-election
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zk-cs
  labels:
    app: zk
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 2181
      name: client
  selector:
    app: zk
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: zk-pdb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  maxUnavailable: 1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zk
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zk
  serviceName: zk-hs
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zk
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - zk
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-zookeeper
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1Gi"
              cpu: "0.5"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
              name: client
            - containerPort: 2888
              name: server
            - containerPort: 3888
              name: leader-election
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "start-zookeeper \
          --servers=3 \
          --data_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
          --data_log_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data/log \
          --conf_dir=/opt/zookeeper/conf \
          --client_port=2181 \
          --election_port=3888 \
          --server_port=2888 \
          --tick_time=2000 \
          --init_limit=10 \
          --sync_limit=5 \
          --heap=512M \
          --max_client_cnxns=60 \
          --snap_retain_count=3 \
          --purge_interval=12 \
          --max_session_timeout=40000 \
          --min_session_timeout=4000 \
          --log_level=INFO"
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - sh
                - -c
                - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - sh
                - -c
                - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          volumeMounts:
            - name: datadir
              mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: datadir
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Gi
```

And of course, I got the error **PodUnschedulable**

In this file, I cloud not find anything that says that I need a cluster of 4 nodes and with 2 CPUs and 4G Ram.
So:

- What defines how much of resources do my deployment needs?
- How to understand/calculate the required resources of applications and their respective deployments beforehand?
- Zookeeper runs on 2GB RAM according to requirements but this is only a recommended configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a kubernetes nodes will **not come empty.** Instead, it has running processes before even running your apps workload:

- kubelet is running ( in each node)
- kube-proxy is running as daemonset ( in each node)
- container-runtime (Docker) is running in each node
- other daemonset can be running (like aws-node DS in the case of EKS..).

> We are here discussing Worker Nodes not Masters.

So imagine all that, you will end up by choosing a respectful resources for each Node.

Not all Nodes must be with the same size. However you decide which size you need according to the type of your apps :

- If your apps eats memory more than CPUs (Like Java Apps), you will need to choose Node of **[2CPU, 8GB]** is better than **[4CPUs, 8GB]**.
- If your apps eats CPUs more than memory (Like ML workload), you will need to choose the opposite; computing-optimized instances.
- The golden rule  is to calculate the **whole capacity** is better than looking into the individual capacity for each  node.

This means **3 large** nodes might be better than **4 medium** nodes in term of cost but also in term of the best usage of capacity.

[image]

As conclusion, Node resource must be:

- no less than 2 CPUs
- no less than 4GB memory

Otherwise, you should expect capacity issues.

---

Now, we reach the half of the answer: Identify the capacity of the cluster.

The second half is about answering **how to assign resources for the each app (pod)**.

This is fall into another question; How much your app consume ?

To answer this question, you need to monitor your app with APM tools like Prometheus + Grafana.

Once you get insight about the avergae of consumption, it's the time to set **resources limits** for your app (its pods).

**Limits** might throttle the app, that's why, you need to set up alongside other things for horizontal auto-scaling:

- Run Pods inside Deployment to manage replicas and deployment.
- HPA or  Horizontal Pod autoscaler: which monitors the pods of the deployment , then scale out/in according to thresholds (CPU, memory)

As conclusion for this part, we can say:

**- Measure :** start measure to identify `resources.limits` and `resources.requests`.

**- Measure:** measure after running the app to identify again the needed resources.

**- Measure:** Keep measure

Answer (score 1):

`resources` section in the deployment yaml defines the resource requirement of a container in the pod.

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "0.5"
```

`requests` means a node need to have more than 1GB of memory and 0.5 CPU available for one of the replica pod to be schedulable on that node.

There is another concept of `limits` which defines maximum resource a pod is allowed to consume before it get's evicted from the node.

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "0.5"
  limits:
    memory: "2Gi"
    cpu: "2"
```

Although you have 3 nodes the master node is not schedule by default.

You can understand the resource availability of a node by `kubectl describe nodename` and checking the `Capacity` and `Allocatable` section.

```
Capacity:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  8065444Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16424256Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                4
  ephemeral-storage:  7433113179
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16321856Ki
  pods:               110
```

Regarding calculating resource requirement(`requests` and `limits`) of a pod there is no silver bullet. It depends on the application and should be determined and tuned by profiling it. But it's recommended best practice to define `requests` and `limits` when deploying a pod.